# django Get Distinct rows which are inserted last

Tags: django

I have a table which same as bellow

```
id|user|datetime|action
```

this table records actions for each user and its time I want to get latest actions which are done by all users. I have tested these methods

```
Entry.objects.order_by('datetime','user').distinct('user')
```

and

```
Entry.objects.latest('datetime').distinct('user')
```

but both of them returns errors. for example the second try says :

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON expressions must match initial ORDER BY expressions
```

How can I filter rows by latest actions which are done by all users?

Comment: I don't understand why `Entry.objects.latest('datetime').distinct('user')` gives you an error. The syntax is good and it should work.

Comment: @Deadpool sorry my error was from the second try. the first try was returning a wrong answer as I remember

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try with below code:

```
Entry.objects.all().order_by('user', '-datetime').distinct('user')
```

Comment: does `-` before `datetime` has a meaning?

Comment: Yes, you begin by the end to get the last entry

Comment: You can thanks @AstikAnand, but his answer is the solution ;)

Comment: @Deadpool, Thanks

Answer (score 2):

From [django doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.distinct) we have :

> When you specify field names, you must provide an order_by() in the QuerySet, and the fields in order_by() must start with the fields in distinct(), in the same order.